# "docker run" dies after exiting a bash shell script

Tags: bash, docker

I'm attempting to craft system admin bash tools for starting up a Docker image.

But such `docker run` keeps dying on me after its bash script exited.

The actual working bash script in question is:

```
#!/bin/sh

docker run \
    --name publicnginx1 \
    -v /var/www:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro \
    -v /var/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx:ro \
    --rm \
    -p 80 \
    -p 443 \
    -d \
    nginx
docker ps
```

Executing the simple script resulted in:

```
# ./docker-run-nginx.sh 
743a6eaa33f435e3e0d211c4047bc9af4d4667dc31cd249e481850f40f848c83
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                           NAMES
743a6eaa33f4        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   1 second ago        Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:32778->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32777->443/tcp   publicnginx1
```

And after that bash script gets completed, I executed 'docker ps'

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

There is no Docker running.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you run docker logs to see what happened in the container that died?

Comment: weird...  it worked a few days ago.

I had to remove the '--rm' option so I can view the logs post-mortem.

    # docker logs publicnginx1
    2018/07/29 01:50:53 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
    nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)

I'm going to mark this as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run it without --rm.

You can see all container (including the one that already died using this command):

```
> docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     
743a6eaa33f4        nginx   "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   1 second ago         Exited (??) ??                         
                                                                          ^^^^^
```

You should be able to look at what is the exit code of the container. Using the container id, you can also look into it's log to understand better what is going on:

```
docker logs 743a6eaa33f4
```

If you still can't figure it out, you can start the container with tty to run bash, and try to run the command inside it.

```
docker run -it -v /var/www:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -v /var/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx:ro --rm -p 80 -p 443 nginx bash
```

Comment: This is important.  Removing `--rm` option made it possible for such dying container to start appearing in `docker logs` AND `docker ps -a`.   I was now able to see what went wrong with the public nginx Docker image (it was missing a config file).